# SQL Query to search records in multiple tables

Tags: sql

I'm trying to implement a search feature. I need to look into multiple tables in SQL database using a `text-string`. Currently, I'm only looking into 3 tables i.e.,

Table `Items`:

```
[dbo].[Items] 
(
    [ItemID]     INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [CategoryID] INT            NOT NULL,
    [BrandID]    INT            NOT NULL,
    [ItemName]   NVARCHAR(MAX)  NOT NULL,
    [ItemPrice]  DECIMAL(18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [imageUrl]   NVARCHAR(MAX)  NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Items] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ItemID] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Items_dbo.Brands_BrandID] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([BrandID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Brands] ([BrandID]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Items_dbo.Categories_CategoryID] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([CategoryID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Categories] ([CategoryID])
)
```

Table `Categories`:

```
[dbo].[Categories] 
(
    [CategoryID] INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name]       NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Categories] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([CategoryID] ASC)
)
```

Table `Brands`:

```
[dbo].[Brands] 
(
    [BrandID] INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name]    NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Brands] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([BrandID] ASC)
)
```

Any records that may contain the supplied `text-string` must be fetched out. I'm a newbie on SQL knowledge. This is my implementation is:

```
SELECT *
FROM Items
WHERE ItemName LIKE 'cocacola'

SELECT *
FROM Categories
WHERE Name LIKE  'cocacola'

SELECT *
FROM Brands
WHERE Name LIKE 'cocacola'
```

which is obviously incorrect. Can someone please guide.

Thanks.

Comment: why is it "obviously incorrect"? What results does it produce? What results did you expect? We can't see your data. However, I can guess the problem. If you're using LIKE it would make sense to use wildcards. i.e. LIKE `%cocacola%` so that if `cocacola` is in the middle of the field but is not the only thing in the field then it will be matched. Any simple tutorial about the LIKE keyword would show you an example of that. There's really very little point in using `LIKE` unless you include the wildcard - you might as well just use `=` otherwise.

Comment: @ADyson - Thanks for the useful wildcard tip. My desired function I need my query to perform is to search for the keyword 'cocacola' in table `Items` in `ItemName` column first. If there is a match, it should pull out the record and keep it in memory and move to `Categories` and `Brands` table and do the same. Suppose `Items` doesn't contain any record with that match,  then my query should move to table `Categories` and look in `Categories.Name`. If there is no match, then it should move to `Brands` table and look `Brands.Name` for keyword `cocacola`.

Comment: @ADyson - In the end it should combine all records into a list and return. Hope it explains

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to return a substring search, it might be slow depending on how much data you have.

If you are able to pre-specify the tables, and want a single search that searches all and returns matches across all tables, you will want something like this:

```
SELECT 
    'Items' as table_name,
    item_id as record_id,
    ItemName AS found
FROM
    Items
WHERE
    ItemName LIKE '%cocacola%'

UNION

SELECT 
    'Categories' as table_name,
    CategoryID AS record_id,
    Name AS found

FROM
    Categories
WHERE
    Name LIKE '%cocacola%'

UNION

SELECT 
    'Brands' as table_name,
    BrandID AS record_id,
    Name AS found
FROM
    Brands
WHERE
    Name LIKE '%cocacola%'
```

The UNION will append the results from one query to another.

It will be slow if you have a lot of data

Comment: Great work Alan. Your solution solved my issue. Thank You for the guidance.

Comment: Btw, I do have a lot of data. Is there any way possible to improve its speed?

Answer (score 0):

You solution is not incorrect. You run three queries. Each against a different Table. Depending on your use case this is probably fine.

You can join the tables if you want to search all tables with only one query. This is probably slower than running three queries because the database has to match the values together.

```
SELECT *
  FROM Items
  FULL OUTER JOIN Categories ON Categories.CategoryID = Items.CategoryID
  FULL OUTER JOIN Brands ON Brands.BrandID = Items.BrandID
WHERE Items.ItemName LIKE 'cocacola'
  AND Categories.Name LIKE 'cocacola'
  AND Brands.Name LIKE 'cocacola'
```

If you get a hit in the category name with this query, the category will be listed for every item that's associated with this category.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might want to try using a union to join together the results of all three queries.

For example:

```
SELECT ItemID, ItemName
  FROM Items
 WHERE ItemName = 'cocacola'
 UNION
SELECT CategoryID, Name
  FROM Categories
 WHERE Name =  'cocacola'
 UNION
SELECT BrandID, Name
  FROM Brands
 WHERE Name = 'cocacola'
```

One note about union is that you have to make sure that each part of the query is returning the same number of columns with the same datatype in the same order.

Comment: Will it affect speed if I've a lot of data?

Comment: I'm not an expert on query speed, but generally speaking the more data your query has to process, the longer it will take. If you can use = instead of like, that will make it faster because it takes less time to search for an exact match. I used = because I wasn't sure if that's what you meant to use in your example.

Comment: People in my country don't speak English. Since spelling errors are on a high expectation, my concerns were to face and handle it. I thought `LIKE` operator would give me more grounds to cover it.

Comment: Oh, that's interesting. You should know that using LIKE '%cocacola%' would only return data that has "cocacola" at the beginning, middle, or end of it. For example: it would return "xx cocacola xx", but it wouldn't return "coccacola".

Comment: True. I'm going to read more on opting between `=` and `LIKE`. Also, how to handle spelling errors in search functions. Thanks a lot for your time and guidance.